# What could a flying vehicle possess that enables it to move in all direction?

Tags: engineering, flight, vehicles

So I was wondering what a flying vehicle could possess that would enable it to move in all directions at almost any angle. For example it could move upward diagonally while upside down, crazy stuff like that.

The limitations and requirements are as follows:
The vehicle must be manned from the inside by a human being.(don’t take into account how skilled one might need to be.)
The vehicle must be able to move at least 50 m/s in all direction.
The vehicle must have room for a 1 meter by 1 meter handewavium engine.
The vehicle does not need to look like an existing vehicle but can if you see fit.

Please keep in mind this does NOT need to be achievable by current day humanities production limitations but must need to be conceivable and considered possible.

Bonus question: how might this vehicle look? Could it have room to possess weaponry or maybe at least be utilized in combat?

Edit: This flight will be conducted in atmosphere and gravity of earth.

Comment: I'm pretty sure we could build this next week if there were any practical use for it.

Comment: @ZeissIkon If that’s how long it would take to build this, than it should be easy to answer this question. My question is asking for an answer not a reason of why I shouldn’t have asked this question.

Comment: Flight in space or flight in atmosphere + gravity?

Comment: @Tortliena i have made an edit

Comment: A flying vehicle which can move in any direction at will is called a helicopter. About a thousand of them are manufactured each year. The largest manufacturers are Airbus (formerly Eurocopter), Robinson, Sikorsky, Bell Helicopters, and Leonardo (formerly known as AugustaWestland). Plus some manufacturers in Russia and China, which are not counted in western statistics. (Helicopters are not designed to fly inverted, but only because nobody has ever come up with a reasonable use case. There is nothing which to prevent making a helicopter able to fly inverted, if you can come up with a use case.)

Comment: "There is nothing which to prevent making a helicopter able to fly inverted" and as a proof of concept, many R/C model helicopters are routinely flown inverted, including outside loops, inverted hover in and out of ground effect, etc.  Inverted autorotation seems like a problem, but not an insolvable one (procedure would likely be to roll to upright before rotor speed can drop and before starting autorotation procedure).  I'm not sure, however, that helicopters can fly 50 m/s sideways or backward due to stability issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple startups are now developing human-carrying "quadcopter" and similar flying machines.  "All" that's needed to give them this additional capability (within the flight duration of an electric multicopter, anyway) is adding inverted and angled rotors to allow for inverted flight and flight in non-horizontal thrust directions -- plus updating the flight control software and attitude sensing systems to handle intentional flight outside the "normal" parameters the current generation is designed for.

Assuming your unobtainium engine can replace 3-4 times its volume and weight in lithium batteries, your flight duration will then be limited by either the engine's endurance, or the pilot's.